# What happens to the Pandas Dataframe after groupby command in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to figure some things out in Pandas.  I have a dataFrame(df) with 109 rows and 2 distinct "owner_name" values.

Before the groupby command I am able to view the entire contents with:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
  print(df)
```

After I do the groupby using:

```
rdf = df.groupby('owner_name')
```

Now when I do:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
  print(rdf)
```

I get:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fe40fc8d2b0>
```

How do I print out the contents of the rdf dataFrame?

Also how do I cycle through the various rows and columns now?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide an example dataframe for your question!

Comment: There was enough information in the question to provide an answer  It would be great if you could spend a couple of seconds thinking something through before down voting it.

Comment: I asked if it was possible to provide an example dataframe because I wanted to understand your question better. I was not the one who downvoted your question, in fact I do not even have enough reputation to do so. On the other hand I don't think you should take downvoting so personally it's just a measure for people to indicate percieved question and answer quality.

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` `groupby` will return the [groupby object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), if you want to see the detail of each `groupby` subset do with `list`

```
list(df.groupby('a'))
Out[48]: 
[(1,   id  a  b
  0  a  1  1), (2,   id  a  b
  1  b  2  2
  2  c  2  2)]
# in your case list(rdf)
```

Comment: Thanks.  This got me part of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
for owner_name, row in rdf.iterrows():
    for column_name, value in row.items():
```